# jQuery popup box only show once in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

First, let me explain the purpose of the popup. I have a list from a database of products, in a foreach loop.

Now I added code so that when you click the product, it opens a new box and shows content about this product. But for some reason, it only works on the first product.

I will post the code here, since I am very bad at jQuery/Javascript.
Here is the jquery script:

```
;(function($) {
     // DOM Ready
    $(function() {
        // Binding a click event
        // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
        $('#wiki-button').on('click', function(e) {
            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();
            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('#wiki-content').bPopup();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

A snippet from the loop:

```
foreach ($getTheOffers as $getTheOffer ) { ?>
<div id="wiki-content">
        <div class="box9">
            <h1>Sample Box</h1>   
                <img src="imageurl">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam luctus consectetur dolor a porttitor. Curabitur id sem sed ante fringilla pulvinar et id lectus. Nullam justo ipsum, hendrerit ut commodo nec, pellentesque nec erat. Pellentesque pharetra.</p><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

If you need to see more code, I will post it in pastebin.

Comment: Where is the HTML element with 'wiki-button' id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change **id** to **class**. Id should be unique otherwise only the first element will be select

```
;(function($) {
     // DOM Ready
    $(function() {
        // Binding a click event
        // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
        $('.wiki-button').on('click', function(e) {
      //___^_____________    
            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();
            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('.wiki-content').bPopup();
         // ___^___________
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```
foreach ($getTheOffers as $getTheOffer ) { ?>
<div class="wiki-content">
<!-- _____^____________________-->
        <div class="box9">
            <h1>Sample Box</h1>   
                <img src="imageurl">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam luctus consectetur dolor a porttitor. Curabitur id sem sed ante fringilla pulvinar et id lectus. Nullam justo ipsum, hendrerit ut commodo nec, pellentesque nec erat. Pellentesque pharetra.</p><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` instead of `id`

So, in your HTML

```
<div class="wiki-content">
```

And in your jQuery

```
$('.wiki-button').on('click', function(e) {
    // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
    e.preventDefault();
    // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
    $(this).bPopup();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You have repeating ID's. The ID selector only expects one result, and gives you one, the first element. Hence, only the first is working.

**Solution:**

Use classes! Give a common class to your repeating elements and target that.